# Windows XP TCP halts after burst on ZMQ channel

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, tcp

I have a ZMQ application the sends a high rate of data over a TCP connection upon start up. The application runs fine on Windows 7 and Server 2003, but on XP it halts shortly after connection. The app is fine, just the connection seems to be stalled.

Someone mentioned there was a registry tweak for XP that corrects this but I cannot seem to find and info on this specific issue. (This is XP SP3)

I am sending from one XP machine to another with just an ethernet cable and no switches or routers in between.

Other traffic works fine between the two systems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to go away when I set TcpAckFrequency = 1 in the TcpIp parameters registry branch.